# Pandas - How to count days b/w two dates according to custom calendar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

My question is pretty simple, so I'm hoping there is a simple solution.  I want to count the days between two dates, but rather than using full calendar days or business days or business days with a holiday calendar, I want to provide MY OWN "calendar" in the form of a list of dates.

So let's say my dates are ['2019-01-01', '2010-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-10']. I want the dates between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-03' to return 1. Between '2019-01-03' and '2019-01-10' should return 2.

Thanks!

```
# This produces standard calendar days between-
dates_list = df.index
x = dates_list[1] - dates_list[0]

# This produces days according to numpy businessdaycal:
cal = np.busdaycalendar()
x = np.busday_count('2019-01-01', '2019-01-03', busdaycal=cal)

# This works, but requires multiple steps so prob inefficient:
dates_list = df.index
all_dates = pd.date_range(dates_list[0], dates_list[1])
holidays = [d.date() for d in all_dates if d not in dates_list]
cal = np.busdaycalendar(holidays=holidays)
x = np.busday_count('2019-01-01', '2019-01-03', busdaycal=cal)
```

Comment: And what's the problem, what have you tried so far? Where are you stucked at?

Comment: We also need you to define the relationship you have.  How do you "inform" your program how to determine the quantity of days?  You've given two thin examples, not a specification.  On what does the return value depend?  All you've said is that you want to supply your own definition, but you're not telling us what that definition might be, either quantified or parameterized.  There is no "read my mind" algorithm ... as much as we try ... :-)

Comment: Apologies, my attempts thus far were simply not coming close doing the actual trick, but I posted some "wrong" examples". I'd like to do what the numpy example above does, but rather than using numpy's business day calendar, I want to supply MY OWN calendar (which would be created by a list of explicit dates). Then it should do the same thing as the np.busday_count function. Thanks @Prune!

Comment: Where are you stuck?  This appears to be a trivial, one-symbol change: when you call the `count` function, replace the built-in `numpy` calendar with your own.

Comment: Have you tried `series.between().sum()` ? Where`series` contains your custom calendar

Comment: @Prune I just edited the above with a solution that works, but it seems pretty inefficient. The issue is I have a list of dates I want to "include", whereas numpy requires a list of holidays to "exclude" in the calculations.

Comment: Right -- so you take the difference between your calendar and a set of all dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I've got. I tried @RichieV's pd.Series.between() and the following method, which is faster:

```
dates_list = df.index
all_dates = pd.date_range(dates_list[0], dates_list[1])
holidays = [d.date() for d in all_dates if d not in dates_list]
cal = np.busdaycalendar(holidays=holidays)
x = np.busday_count('2019-01-01', '2019-01-03', busdaycal=cal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
import pandas as pd

my_cal = pd.Series(
    data=1, 
    index=pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', periods=100, freq='D'))

# set your own 'holidays' to zero here

# cumulative sum won't count your custom 'holidays'
my_cal = my_cal.cumsum()

# use like this (this could be wrapped in a function)
days_between = my_cal['2020-01-03'] - my_cal['2020-01-01']
print(days_between)
```